# How to handle different type of clients in Netty 4.0

Tags: java, netty

For a server using Netty 4.0,

1) Can i use one handler to handle data coming from clients which are developed in different languages?(for example : c#, flash, objective-c, javascript)

2) Should i use ChannelInboundByteHandler or ChannelInboundMessageHandler for the above situation?

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes ,You can use single handler to handle data coming from different clients.

If your server processes row bytes sent by clients then you can process at server side but if they are sending objects then you should make appropriate objects at server side.

you can get clear idea about handlers from http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/04/21/netty-using-handlers/

2)Answer of second question depends on your requirement you can use any of them as per your requirement.